# Replace part of screen content by using Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

I have a **main Activity** and one **fragment**.

The **main Activity** has the following layout:

```
<FrameLayout
 ...>

 <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/header"
  .../>

 <com.project.fragments.FirstFragment
  .../>


</FrameLayout>
```

As the above layout shows, there is a `<LinearLayout>` with id "`header`", and there is the `FirstFragment` which is part of the screen content.  It works fine so far.

Then, I created **another fragment** class, called `SecondFragment.java` .

In my **main activity** java code, how can I dynamically switch the content between `FirstFragment` and `SecondFragment` meanwhile keep the `<LinearLayout>` (`@+id/header`) part stay on the screen?

(My app is running on a mobile phone not a tablet. Basically, I would like to have part of the screen content change by using fragments, but not sure how to achieve this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some template code for you to use:

```
Fragment newFragment = new SecondFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.header, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null); // Ads FirstFragment to the back-stack
transaction.commit();
```